# Joomla first installation error tables didn't exist

Tags: mysql, joomla, installation, joomla3.0

I have start to a fresh installation of joomla 3.7.2 and i have get the error below after hitting the button install.

```
Error
Table 'joomla_try.#__viewlevels' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__utf8_conversion' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__usergroups' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__update_sites_extensions' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__update_sites' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__template_styles' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__tags' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__postinstall_messages' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__modules_menu' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__modules' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__menu_types' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__menu' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__languages' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__finder_terms_common' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__finder_taxonomy' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__extensions' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__content_types' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__categories' doesn't exist
Table 'joomla_try.#__assets' doesn't exist
Query was empty
```

The installation create the database into my server but stops there nothing is created in it.
Also i have tried to create a database and give it when it is asked at the installation process but the same thing happens.

```
Server specs: 

    mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.47    
    PHP 5.3.10 
    Apache/2.2.3
```

Comment: Sounds like permission issues...

Comment: It is my thought also.....but what and where ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Only think i was need to change was at the installation/sql/mysql 
to change everything int the xxxxx.sql files from utf8mbxxxxx to utf8xxxx

It was weird though because my Mysql server at 5.5.56 suppose to support the utf8mb.